# Amplifier IC naming/labeling

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit

I am currently building (trying to build) a portable speaker system. With a basic aux cable input and a small amplifier circuit for use outdoors.

With a salvaged TEA2025b IC and an assortment of capacitors lying around I started the build. The [build](http://www.instructables.com/id/Stereo-Audio-Amplifier/?ALLSTEPS) I followed seemed to work as the speakers did produced sound albeit very faint. After further experimentation and a few bad decisions later I blew the IC.

After a while I manage to get my hands on a BT2025BH IC chip from Boomtech, salvaged from a different set of speakers. Now the question I have is that can this chip be used as a direct replacement for the TEA2025 IC or are they completely different and only coincidently have the same number code?

Also are there any standard in naming IC’s of this sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the datasheets for each and compare.

Even if the datasheets show similar performance and ratings there might be subtle differences, or the parts could be absolutely identical inside with different markings. There is no way to tell without investigating.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I had trouble finding the datasheet for the BT2025BH IC. I went ahead and did a direct drop in replacement anyway. It did work surprisingly well and with a few tweaks it was perfect.